# Not found for content files when I use AppComponent's selector in NOT main page

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I try to use Angular2 in ASP.NET app.

The Angular's scripts (as it descripted in [QuickStart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)) are declared in _Layout.cshtml, but when I use selector of AppComponent in the view of some controller:

```
<my-app>please, Angular, load here something...</my-app>
```

with request's path.../Home/Index

then Angular's infrastructure try to load needed modules from .../Home/...js not from the root folder.

In my cause zone.js get 404-error when it requests main.js file from .../**Home**/app/main.js but this folder is located in the root.

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have special tag to set base url angular will use to generate urls.

```
<base href="/">
```

From documentation

> You must add a  element to the app's index.html for
>   pushState routing to work. The browser uses the base href value to
>   prefix relative URLs when referencing CSS files, scripts, and images.
>
> Add the base element just after the  tag. If the app folder is
>   the application root, as it is for this application, set the href
>   value in index.html exactly as shown here.

Just try to play with this parameters to tune your urls prefix.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href